# InfoPath Designer 2010. Can't connect to SharePoint 2010 Lists

Tags: infopath

I'm using InfoPath 2010 (32-bit) to design forms for a form library that is stored on a SharePoint 2010 server. In the past, others been able to create a data connection to pull data from a list on the server, but I have been encountering an error whenever I try to add a new connection in a new form or modify an old connection in an older form. The error message I receive is:

"InfoPath has encountered an error. The operation failed. Not enough storage is available to process this command."

After doing some research, the only solution I was able to find suggested editing the IRPStackSize key in my registry (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106167). This hasn't had any impact on the issue.

Can anyone provide me with an idea of what is causing this issue and how it can be resolved.

Comment: are you using https?

Comment: Hi did you ever find a solution for this. I am having the same problem. Thanks!